# Android Studio. Not deploy/run app to emulator 4.3

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.3.2
Emulator 4.3
[image]

In prompt show list devices:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

But when I try to run app from Android Studio I get black screen on emulator (Android 4.3) and nothing happened. Here screen:

[image]

On another emulator (e.g. 7.1) I success deploy and run app.
Here my sdk settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using other emulators like Genymotion or Memu, or on an actual device[best], for running apps built on AndroidStudio if you are working in Windows. The default emulator is very very slow in my experience, you need a PC with some real high specification.

Well you do have the APIS and other things necessary, so I think your emulator is just too slow to load, or not compatible with your PC , so its not loading.

Comment: Windows 10 (64 bit). RAM 8 GB, Intel 3 GHz.  I has some emulators. Emulator 4.0 - success run, Emulator 7.1 - success run, but Emulator 4.3 - not run.